# error running rake db:migrate:down

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, migration, rake, migrate

i would like to know how can i redo a migration in rails, my problem is that i already run: rake db:migrate:redo VERSION=xxx... but this display an error saying that the table do not exist, i am assuming that the problem occure running db:migrate:down, but when i try to run the db:migrate:up this one do not nothing :/

i want to create that table using that migration, how can i do that?

my alternative is creating a new migration, but i would like to know if there is another way to solve it.

thx :)

Comment: run rake db:reset this will drop all table and run all your migration

Comment: ^-- definitely do not do that. There is no reason to drop your entire database because of one migration. Usually this just involves commenting out part of a migration in order to run the whole thing, and then restoring it. Why don't you post your migration code so people can see.

Comment: Thx @kdeisz, i just were commenting until reach to a point were i could run rake db:migrate:down and up without problems :)

Answer (score 1):

Please use rake db:migrate:down VERSION=VERSION_NUMBER

DO not use rake db:migrate:redo VERSION=XXX